# Is `\coffin_gattach:…` not really global?

Tags: expl3, bugs, xcoffins

Below is an MWE that typesets “AB”, as it should. However, if one uncomments the `\group_begin:` and `\group_end:`, the B disappears—i.e., the attachment seems to be performed locally, despite the use of the global attachment command. If `gattach` is replaced by `gjoin`, it works, so *that* command is global. (If one replaces `gjoin` by `join`, the B once again disappears, as it should.) Is this an `l3coffins` bug?

I had a quick look at the `l3coffins` source, and see that the local/global difference seems to be handled in the same way in both the `attach` and `join` commands. When defining `\coffin_join:…` and `\coffin_attach:…`, `\coffin_set_eq:NN` is used, while for `\coffin_gjoin:…` and `\coffin_gattach:…`, `\coffin_gset_eq:NN` is used. It seems this should have worked, but somehow it doesn't seem to?

(Note that I've also included a simple workaround: If the grouping statements are uncommented in the original MWE, so that the B disappears, and one *also* uncomments the line with `\coffin_gset_eq:NN`, the B once again reappears, indicating that the attachment is performed correctly, but locally.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\coffin_new:N \coffin_a
\coffin_new:N \coffin_b

\hcoffin_set:Nn \coffin_a {A}
\hcoffin_set:Nn \coffin_b {B}

% \group_begin: % Hides the attachment
\coffin_gattach:NnnNnnnn \coffin_a H r \coffin_b H l {0pt} {0pt}
% \coffin_gset_eq:NN \coffin_a \coffin_a % Workaround
% \group_end:

\NewDocumentCommand \ShowCoffins { } {
    \coffin_typeset:Nnnnn \coffin_a H l {0pt} {0pt}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\ShowCoffins
\end{document}
```

Comment: Definitely a bug.  In the definition of `\__coffin_attach:NnnNnnnnN`, the last line should read `#9 #1 \l__coffin_aligned_coffin`, but instead it is `\coffin_set_eq:NN #1 \l__coffin_aligned_coffin`.  I'll fix

Comment: Ah, great! If you'd like to make this an answer, I'd be happy to accept it. Also, should I report the bug on GitHub (or would you like to, since you know what's going on)?-)

Comment: [Committed already](https://github.com/latex3/latex3/commit/282e813f).  My editing skills are restricted right now (using github's web editor :), so at night I'll add some tests and merge, but for the next release this should be fixed.

Comment: That's great! :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was a bug in `\coffin_gattach:NnnNnnnn`.  The last line in the definition of `\__coffin_attach:NnnNnnnnN` should read:

```
  #9 #1 \l__coffin_aligned_coffin
```

where `#9` is either `\coffin_set_eq:NN` or `\coffin_gset_eq:NN`, depending which function you used.  However the code was using `\coffin_set_eq:NN` unconditionally, so the assignment was always local.

This is now [fixed](https://github.com/latex3/latex3/commit/282e813fd7db9c30957ce9c7f2e080a13bdc4f70), and should work properly in the next release:

```
--- a/l3kernel/l3coffins.dtx
+++ b/l3kernel/l3coffins.dtx
@@ -1984,7 +1984,7 @@
     \@@_offset_poles:Nnn #4
       { \l_@@_offset_x_dim } { \l_@@_offset_y_dim }
     \@@_update_vertical_poles:NNN #1 #4 \l_@@_aligned_coffin
-    \coffin_set_eq:NN #1 \l_@@_aligned_coffin
+    #9 #1 \l_@@_aligned_coffin
   }
 \cs_new_protected:Npn \@@_attach_mark:NnnNnnnn #1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8
   {
```